# grepping particular matrix and printing it in single row

Tags: shell-script

I have one file that contains key words `word1` and `word2` and under `word2` there is a matrix as 
**file.dat**

```
  position1: [    0.0000000,    0.0000000,    0.0000000 ]
  word1:    0.0000000
  band:
  - # 1
    word2 :
    0.32015595   0.18484212   0.00000000
    0.00000000   0.36968424   0.00000000
    0.00000000   0.00000000   0.08286072 

  position2: [    0.5000000,    0.0000000,    0.0000000 ]
  word2:    0.0000000
  band:
  - # 1
    word2 :
    0.45015595   0.53484212   0.00000000
    0.00000000   0.36968424   0.00000000
    0.00000000   0.00000000   0.02476072 
    .
    .
```

Now i  want make a file of the format

```
position1 word1 word2
position2 word1 word2
.
.
```

but here word2 matrix in single line as

```
0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000  0.0000000    0.32015595   0.18484212 0.00000000 0.00000000   0.36968424   0.00000000 0.00000000   0.00000000 0.08286072
```

i have used the commend

```
awk '/ position | word1 | word2/ {w=w "$2" } END {print w}
```

but it is not giving the expected result can anyone help me?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F': ' '/position[0-9]+:|word[0-9]+:/ {w=w" "$2 };
              /^[0-9. ]+$/ { w=w" "$0 };
              /^[[:blank:]]*$/ || eof {if (w) {gsub(/,/,"",w);print w;w=""}}' muthu.txt 
 [    0.0000000    0.0000000    0.0000000 ]    0.0000000     0.32015595   0.18484212   0.00000000     0.00000000   0.36968424   0.00000000     0.00000000   0.00000000   0.08286072 
 [    0.5000000    0.0000000    0.0000000 ]    0.0000000     0.45015595   0.53484212   0.00000000     0.00000000   0.36968424   0.00000000     0.00000000   0.00000000   0.02476072
```

Alternatively, with (IMO) slightly nicer formatting:

```
$ awk -F': ' '/position[0-9]+:/ {p=$2 };

              /word[0-9]+:/ {w=$2};

              /^[0-9. ]+$/ {
                  if (!w2) { w2="[" };
                  w2=w2" ["$0" ]"
              };

              /^[[:blank:]]*$/ || eof {
                  l=p" "w" "w2;
                  gsub(/  +/," ",l);
                  gsub(/,/,"",l);
                  if (l ~ /^[[:blank:]]*$/) {next};
                  print l" ]";
                  p=w=w2=""
              }' muthu.txt 
[ 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 ] 0.0000000 [ [ 0.32015595 0.18484212 0.00000000 ] [ 0.00000000 0.36968424 0.00000000 ] [ 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.08286072 ] ]
[ 0.5000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 ] 0.0000000 [ [ 0.45015595 0.53484212 0.00000000 ] [ 0.00000000 0.36968424 0.00000000 ] [ 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.02476072 ] ]
```

Both of these assume that the input is in paragraphs separated by 1 or more blank lines.

Comment: Thank you cas. but if you explain it bit longer than it would be better as i not able to understand eof {} block completely as i'm newbie for awk world and thank you for your answer

Comment: I'll describe it for the second version of the `awk` script (the first is similar but a little less complex):  that block is executed if the input line is a blank line OR we have reached the end of the input file.  It constructs a line (in variable `l`) with the `p`, `w`, and `w2` variables which were created from other matching lines.  Then it uses the `gsub()` function to make changes to `l` (removing excess spaces and commas).  Finally, if `l` is empty, do nothing otherwise print it and clear the `p`,`w`, and `w2` variables.

Comment: thanks cas. could you explain purpose of $ in your awk command  such as /^[[:blank:]]*$/    whether is means the search pattern is to be carried out upto end of line

Comment: `$` is the end-of-line anchor in regular expressions, and `^` is the beginning-of-line anchor.  `/^[[:blank:]]*$/` matches lines that are either completely empty or contain only blank characters (tabs and spaces).